# SQL - get the last changed unique values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
key data created
1   a    14:15
2   b    14:16
2   c    14:17
1   a    14:18
3   b    14:19
3   c    14:20
3   a    14:21
1   b    14:22
2   c    14:23
2   c    14:24
```

I want to get the last 2 unique keys with the latest data inserted. in other word, i want a query that will get me: 1,2

but when I do something like this:

```
SELECT distinct(key) FROM logs ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

or this:

```
SELECT key FROM logs GROUP BY key ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

I only get: 2,3
probably because these are the last keys in the table.
I couldn't figure out how to get the 2 keys with the latest data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT `key`, MAX( `created` ) AS `maxcreated`
FROM `logs`
GROUP BY `key`
ORDER BY `maxcreated` DESC 
LIMIT 0,2
```

You did not select the maximum (that is the the latest creation time) per key.

So just use `GROUP BY` to select per `key` and add a `MAX( created )` to select the last appearance for each `key`. Applying the respective `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses, you get the desired result.

[**Example Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac059/2)